# MetaIO progressDialog freezes when loading SDK

Tags: java, android, augmented-reality

I am quite new to Android/Java, and my first app is using MetaIO SDK.

I am trying to implement "Loading" progress bar, while app (MetaIO SDK) is loading.

1. Overlay background is shown
2. Loading dialog is appeared and "loading image" starts spinning
3. **Overlay background disappears and loading image stops spinning** <- the problem
4. After 2-3 seconds it unfreezes and ARELViewActivity is executed.

The code:

```
public void onScanButtonClick(View v)
{
  new ScanLoadingDialog().execute(0);
}

private class ScanLoadingDialog extends AsyncTask<Integer, Integer, Boolean>
{
  //Before running code in separate thread
  @Override
protected void onPreExecute()
{
    progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
    progressDialog.setMessage("Loading");
    progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
    progressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
    progressDialog.show();
}

@Override
protected Boolean doInBackground(Integer... params)
{
  try
  {
    synchronized (this) {
      AssetsManager.extractAllAssets(getApplicationContext(), true);
      startActivity( new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ARELViewActivity.class));
    }

  }
  catch (IOException e)
  {
    MetaioDebug.log(Log.ERROR, "Error extracting assets: "+e.getMessage());
    MetaioDebug.printStackTrace(Log.ERROR, e);
    return false;
  }

  return true;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result)
{
  progressDialog.dismiss();
  finish();
}
```

}

Am I doing something wrong?

P.S. Full source code can be found here: [link text](https://github.com/cidevant/ebag-scanner-android/blob/master/EbagScanner/src/com/armed/ebagscanner/MainActivity.java)
P.S.S. Related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7939563/android-ui-freezes-instead-of-displaying-progressdialog), but I am using technique suggested there, and it still doesn't want to work

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and i solved it by running the UI handling code on the UI thread like so

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
  @Override
  public void run() {
    if (imgvExampleOverlay != null) 
        imgvExampleOverlay.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
  });
```

**imgvExampleOverlay** is an image like the one the user has to capture.

Hope this helps